Is it legal for my landlord to demand payments outside of those required in our contract if he didn't specify a penalty if I didn't pay him?
My landlord spoke to me about his intent to come into our house to repair things the week before I was scheduled to move out and I agreed I had no problem with this but wouldn't be there.  He later sent me a text basically saying that it was unacceptable I had things in my space he had to move around or clean up to get to where he wanted and said I would have to pay him 50 dollars for the inconvenience.
Now I know I have no legal obligation to make such a payment.  I'm allowed to use my personal space however I see fit -subject to a few restrictions that just don't apply here - until the day I move out regardless of his convenience.  No where in the contract does it say that it must always be convenient for my landlord to walk through my personal space.  I've told him I would not make such a payment, in fact right now my landlord is greatly regretting that text as it inspired me to stick to my legal rights rather then trying to make my moving out more convenient for his own timing.
Still I'm wondering rather his actions were technically legal.  He said I had to pay him money, but he did not set any penalty, make any threat, or otherwise give a clear implication of any negative repercussion that would occur if I didn't pay him.  Was his demanding I give him money without a threat of repercussion if not paid legal?
For the record I'm not planning to act on any information given here, I've already stood up to him in a way I feel is both legal and sufficient; I've decided to limit my response to less then I'd be legally allowed to avoid a disproportionate response.  The point being I'm not planning to take legal action against him, I simply would like to know so I could inform him if he was in violation of any laws to discourage his trying to bully future leaser's in a similar manner.
I'm located in Maryland.

If there's nothing in the lease about this, it seems unlikely that he has a legal right to this.

I know he doesn't have a legal right to the money, the question is rather he is breaking the law by demanding it with an implication I owe him money.

I don't think there's a law against demanding things you don't have a right to.

You are obligated, given a notice, to provide access. It sounds like you didn't since the landlord had to move your stuff around to get to where they needed. Given what you described, I'm not as sure as you are that you're in the right.

"No where in the contract does it say that it must always be convenient for my landlord to walk through my personal space." But presumably the landlord informed you of a time and date and the area he needed to access, which is almost certainly set out in the agreement. If the landlord is holding a deposit, he might retain $50, so then you'll have to take action to reclaim it, if you feel justified.
